# How to redirect to another url after detect face in django

Tags: python, django

The overall idea is that I want to redirect from a page to home page after detect face in Django framework. Tried to manipulate the return but failed to do so and no have any affect. I realised it will redirect to `/camera` after detect page and will not redirect to desired page. This is views.py in django.

```
import cv2
import threading
from django.views.decorators import gzip
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, render_to_response, HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login as _login, logout as _logout
from django.http import JsonResponse,HttpResponseRedirect
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse
def handler404(request):
    response = render_to_response('404.html', {})
    response.status_code = 404
    return response

def home(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(login)
    return render(request, "home.html" )

class VideoCamera(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0 + cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
        self.video.set(3, 640) # set video widht
        self.video.set(4, 320) # set video height
        # Define min window size to be recognized as a face
        minW = 0.2*self.video.get(3)
        minH = 0.2*self.video.get(4)
        (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.video.read()
        threading.Thread(target=self.update, args=()).start()   


    def __del__(self):
        self.video.release()

    def get_frame(self):
        image = self.frame
        minW = 0.2*self.video.get(3)
        minH = 0.2*self.video.get(4)
        face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('static/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale( 
            gray,
            scaleFactor = 1.3,
            minNeighbors = 4,
            minSize = (int(minW), int(minH)),
            )
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
            roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        if any(map(len, faces)):
            image=0
            return image
        else:
            ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
            return jpeg.tobytes()

    def update(self):
        while True:
            (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.video.read()


cam = VideoCamera()


def gen(camera):
        while True:
            frame = cam.get_frame()
            print(frame)
            if(frame==0):
                #threading.Thread(target=cam.update, args=()).join()
                cam.__del__
                //i want to redirect to home page here
                break
            else:
                yield(b'--frame\r\n'
                        b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')
        return frame



@gzip.gzip_page
def livefe(request):
        try:
            return StreamingHttpResponse(gen(VideoCamera()), content_type="multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=frame")
        except: 
            return redirect(handler404)
```

This is part of urls.py

```
    url(r'^home/', view=views.home),
    url(r'^404/', view=views.handler404),
    url(r'^camera/', view=views.livefe),
```

I appreciate any help. Thank you. If django cannot work this out, i appreciate any alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should set name for your url. like this :

```
url(r'^404/', view=views.handler404,name='handler_404')
```

Then you can try this :

```
return redirect('x : handler_404')
```

***-set your django app name instead of x***

***-handler_404 is your url name that i set***

Comment: django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: '**MY APP NAME**' is not a registered namespace

Comment: what is your app name?

Comment: my app name is **Advertisement**

Comment: these 3 urls in your question,was used in this app(Advertisement)?

Comment: you should set the app name that you want to use its url

Comment: url(r'^home/', view=views.home,name='home'),

Comment: if these 3 urls are in Advertisement,you should set these 3 urls with this app name:"Advertisement"

Comment: `return redirect('Advertisement : home')` I did like this but cnt

Comment: I got it.you should set your app name in your urls file.above urlpatterns write this: app_name='Advertisement'

Comment: Hi 
`app_name='Advertisement'
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^home/', view=views.home,name="home"),]`
This still give me same error.

Comment: sorry friend,I gave you everything I knew and i don't know anymore .

Comment: is okay. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def view(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/your-url/")
```

Comment: `def gen(camera):
  while True:
   frame = cam.get_frame()
   #print(frame)
   if(frame==0):
    #threading.Thread(target=cam.update, args=()).join()
    cam.__del__
    
    break
   else:
    yield(b'--frame\r\n'
      b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')
  return HttpResponseRedirect("/home")`

Comment: I tried to put it in this function but will not redirect to homepage also

Comment: append '/'  in  "/home/"

Comment: "GET /camera/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7643. I got this after detect face and didnt redirect to home page.

Answer (score 0):

```
@gzip.gzip_page
def livefe(request):
        try:
            return StreamingHttpResponse(gen(VideoCamera()), content_type="multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=frame")
        except: 
            return redirect('../handler_404') #return redirect('../url-name')
```

Comment: Hi, I tried but no effect because it will not go error.