# How to redirect from StreamingHttpResponse in Django

Tags: python, django, opencv

I would like to achieve this flow:

1. User's face is detected by webcam in homepage
2. The app takes the attendance of the user, display a webpage with the attendance details
3. The attendance details page will redirect back to the homepage after few seconds with the webcam still running

As of now, my app is able to take the attendance of the user but will not render to the attendance details page even though I used return render(). It will remain on the homepage with the webcam still running. Is there a way I can solve this problem or am I getting something wrong? I have tried changing the request details manually like this but it is not working.

```
request.resolver_match = resolve('/takeAttendance/')
        request.path='/takeAttendance/'
        request.path_info='/takeAttendance/'
```

A problem similar to [How to redirect to another url after detect face in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59810469/how-to-redirect-to-another-url-after-detect-face-in-django) but none of the answers worked for me.
The involved code is as below:

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponse , StreamingHttpResponse
from datetime import datetime, date
import cv2
import face_recognition
import numpy as np
import threading

foundFace = False
vs = cv2.videoCapture(0)
lock = threading.Lock()
frame = None

def videoFeed(request):
        return StreamingHttpResponse(getFace(request),content_type="multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=frame")

def getFace(request):
    global vs,outputFrame,lock,foundFace
    known_face_names,known_face_encodings = getFiles() # get the image files from my project directory
    face_location = []
    face_encoding = []
    while foundFace==False:
        check,frame = vs.read()
        small_frame = cv2.resize(frame,(0,0),fx=0.5,fy=0.5)
        face_roi = small_frame[:,:,::-1]
        face_location = face_recognition.face_locations(face_roi)
        face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(face_roi,face_location)
        face_names = []
        names=[]
        for encoding in face_encoding:
            matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings,np.array(encoding),tolerance=0.6)
            distances = face_recognition.face_distance(known_face_encodings,encoding)
            matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings,np.array(encoding),tolerance=0.6)
            distances = face_recognition.face_distance(known_face_encodings,encoding)
            best_match_index = np.argmin(distances) 

            if matches[best_match_index]:
                name = known_face_names[best_match_index]
                face_names.append(name)
                if name not in names:
                    names.append(name)
        #process the frame (add text and rectangle, add the name of the identified user to names)
        with lock:
            (flag,encodedImg) = cv2.imencode(".jpg",frame)
            
        if len(names)!=0:
            foundFace=True
        if foundFace==True:
            takeAttendance(request,names)
            foundFace==False
        yield(b'--frame\r\n' b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + 
            bytearray(encodedImg) + b'\r\n')

def takeAttendance(request,names):
    context={}
    if request.method=='GET':
        if user_id in names:
            attendance = Attendance(user_ID = str(user_id),
                                            date_in = date.today(),
                                            time_in = datetime.now())
            attendance.save()
            context={'attendance':attendance}
            messages.success(request,'Check in successful')
            return render(request,'Attendance/attendance.html',context)
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Check in failed')
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        return redirect('home')
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns=[
    path('home/',views.home,name='home'),
    path('takeAttendance/',views.takeAttendance,name='takeAttendance'),
    path('videoFeed/',views.videoFeed,name='videoFeed'),

]
```

I'm using Django 3.1 and I'm quite new to it, thank you!

#### Edit

Actually I would like to redirect to `Attendance.html` but keep the video stream running, like in a loop so I can redirect from `Attendance.html` to the webcam page with **Javascript** and still have the video stream running. Sorry for not making it clear.

Comment: As I can see `attendance.html` should be returned if face check passed. Is it happens?

Comment: @rzlvmp that's exactly what I want it to do. However it still stays on the same page with the webcam on it and does not redirect to `attendance.html`. That's why I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

Oh... why I didn't notice that...

The problem is:

```py
...
        if foundFace==True:
            takeAttendance(request,names)
...
```

Yes, you execute function that returns render output inside `getFace`. And that's all, `getFace` don't use return value at all.

Correct code should be like:

```py
...
        if foundFace==True:
            returned_render = takeAttendance(request,names)
            return returned_render
...
```

or simply:

```py
...
        if foundFace==True:
            return takeAttendance(request,names)
            # or maybe you should use yield instead of return?
            # I don't know. Check both
            yield takeAttendance(request,names)
...
```

Comment: So I tried `return` but it will stop the video stream, even when I try refreshing the page. Is there a way where I can `return` it but still have my video stream running? I will redirect back to the page with the webcam stream from `Attendance.html` after few seconds using Javascript. And nope `yield` did not work the trick. Thanks for your answer tho.